# StoreKit in TVMLKit

Tags: swift, tvos, storekit, tvml, tvjs

I am trying to find really any resources that show me how to either bridge StoreKit to tvJS and actually use it, or a sane way to pass the data back and forth from Swift to tvJS.

I already have SKProducts being populated in Swift and the bridge between Swift and the JS code, but for some reason those SKProducts come through with no data in them. So, before I go too deep down that rabbit hole, I thought I would ask the internet if there is a better way?

Surely Apple in all it's wisdom has a simpler way since they have such a nice and easy productTemplate built into TVML.

Thanks!